# How to test single file Vue components

Tags: javascript, testing, vue.js, ava

I would like to use `ava` for unit testing my `Vue` components. Right now I have a very simple setup:

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "vue-testing",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "es2015"
        ]
    },
    "ava": {
        "require": [
            "babel-register",
            "./test/helpers/setup-browser-env.js"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "ava": "^0.18.1",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
        "browser-env": "^2.0.21"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.1.10"
    }
}
```

**./test/helpers/setup-browser-env.js**

```
import browserEnv from 'browser-env';

browserEnv();
```

**./test/Notification.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
import test from 'ava';
import Notification from '../src/Notification';

let vm;

test.beforeEach(t => {
    let N = Vue.extend(Notification);

    vm = new N({ propsData: {
        message: 'Foobar'
    }}).$mount();
});


test('that it renders a notification', t => {
    t.is(vm.$el.textContent, 'FOOBAR');
});
```

**src/Notification.js**

```
export default {
    template: '<div><h1>{{ notification }}</h1></div>',
    props: ['message'],
    computed: {
        notification() {
            return this.message.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
};
```

When I run `ava` everything works as expected: `1 passed`.

I'd be more happy if I could use the following component syntax:

**./src/Notification.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ notification }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
     props: ['message'],

    computed: {
        notification() {
            return this.message.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But then `ava` will return the following error:

```
> 1 | <template>
    | ^
  2 |     <div>
  3 |         <h1>{{ notification }}</h1>
  4 |     </div>
```

I can't figure out how to make this work, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

You need to compile .vue files into JavaScript before running them.

**Solution**

You can run vue-loader on modules as you require them using [vue-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-node).

Run `npm install --save-dev vue-node`, to add vue-node to your project

In your /helpers dir, create a setup.js file

Add the following:

```
const hook = require('vue-node');
const { join } = require('path');

// Pass an absolute path to your webpack configuration to the hook function.
hook(join(__dirname, './path/to/webpack.config.js'));
```

Where `./path/to/webpack.config.js` is the path to a webpack config with `vue-loader`, relative to your project.

In package.json, add

```
"ava": {
  "require": [
    "./test/helpers/setup.js"
  ]
},
```

as a property.

You can see a working example repo here - https://github.com/eddyerburgh/avoriaz-ava-example

**Alternatives**

[This thread](https://github.com/avajs/ava/issues/1276) showcases a few ways of testing with ava.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ notification }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
     props: ['message'],

    computed: {
        notification() {
            return this.message.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

What i do is, when starting a new file I usually use this template

```
<template>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

and then i start to write code

here's more info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that `export default` is already in the code, I've updated my question. The error remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with petrol https://github.com/MGMonge/petrol

and do something like that

```
import Notification from "../src/Notification.vue";
import VueTestCase from "petrol/core/VueTestCase.js";

export default class NotificationTest extends VueTestCase {
    beforeEach() {
        this.SUT = this.mount(Notification, {message: 'soMe MeSSagE'});
    }

    /** @test */
    it_converts_message_to_upper_case() {
        this.assertEquals('SOME MESSAGE', this.SUT.notification);
    }
}
```